# Prooving that a set of formulas is satisfiable

Tags: logic, model-theory, predicate-logic

I have to prove that the set of the following formulas is satisfiable

$$
\forall x \forall y(p(x,y) \&p(y,x)) \implies x=y \\
\neg\forall x (p(x,x)) \\
\forall x \exists y \exists z(p(x,y) \&p(z,x)) \\
\neg \forall x \forall y(\neg p(x,y) \lor \neg p(y,x)) 
$$

What I have so far is the following:

$\mathscr A =<A,\sigma,I>$ where $\mathscr A$ is a structure, **A** is the domain of discourse, $\sigma$ is the signature and **I** is the interpretation function.

I've drawn a graph from which I've the following tuples for the predicate p:

$\{(a,d), (b,a),(c,a),(c,b),(c,c),(d,c),(d,b),(d,d)\}$ where a,b,c,d are constant symbols.

My question is how can I best describe my solution rigorously and formally? How does the interpretation function **I** is defined for the following structure?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: By 'decidable' you mean: is there a routine that is able to decide whether or not this set of sentences is consistent? (the answer to which is a trivial yes) ... Or do you mean whether or not the set of sentences is consistent?  Or are you not talking about consistency at all?

Comment: I'm sorry, wrong translation to English. I believe the correct word is 'satisfiable'. I have to prove that the structure has a model. I've edited the post.

Comment: Assuming that the set of tuples interpreting $p$ is correct; the elements are not *constant* symbols but elements of the domain **A** of the structure, i.e. **A** $= \{ a, b, c, d \}$.

Comment: If so, the set of tuples is the subset of **A** $\times$ **A** that interprets the predicate symbol $p$.

Comment: The *signature* is the language; in addition to logical symbols, the language has: no *constant* symbols, one (binary) *predicate* symbol: $p$, and no *function* symbols.

Comment: Thus, calling $P$ the set of tuples you have defined, the interpretation $I$ is a map $I$ that assigns to the only element of $\sigma$ (i.e. to $p$) the set $P$, i.e. $p^I=P$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Mauro says, $a,b,c,d$ are not constant symbols, but *objects* that are elements from your domain. And your set of tuples is $I(p)$ or $p^I$.

And yes, your interpretation is indeed a model of the set of sentences. Hence, the set of sentences is satisfiable.

Comment: What I need, as I've stated in my question, is a rigorous way to write the solution. What $\mathscr A$ equals to? $\mathscr A = <A, \sigma ,I>$ A=? $\sigma=?, I=?$

Comment: Sorry!  $A = \{ a,b,c,d\}$.  $\sigma = < \emptyset, \{ p \}, \{ (p,2) \} >$ (it's a triple, where the first entry indicates there are no functin symbols, the second entry indicates that $p$ is a ( the only) predicate symbol, and the third entry indicates that $p$ is of arity $2$.) $I = \{ (p,\{ (a,d),(d,a),...,(d,d) \}) \}$. That is, $I$ is a function that maps predicate symbol $p$ to the 2-place relation as you defined (and $I$ does not map any pther symbol to anything, since $p$ is the only symbol in the signature.